# c# Delegate: How to invoke ALL methods on an event (Delegate) with potencial exception?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I use `System.Action` as my delegate.

```
public event Action myEvent;
myEvent+=MyMethod1;
myEvent+=MyMethod2;
```

And somewhere else

```
myEvent.Invoke();
```

Now the problem is, `MyMethod1()` will somethimes have Exception when invoked. But I still want `MyMethod2()` be called during this invoke.

How to do that?

About the potencial Exception:
This is actually an Unity issue, when a method registered to an event, and this method contains gameobject interaction. When the related MonoBehaviour deleted, this method still exist, but the gameobject interaction will throw exception.

Comment: Can you not catch the exception within the event handlers?

Comment: I can, but I want to do it in the delegate or event code, because it's more clearer in Unity. And I don't want to add Unity tag because it's actually pure C# question.

Comment: I don't know why you think it's "more clearer" but it is wrong. I would go with Luaan's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `myEvent.Invoke`, you can use `GetInvocationList`:

```
    foreach(var dele in myEvent.GetInvocationList())
    {
        try
        {
            dele.DynamicInvoke();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //If possible, change the above type to be more specific
            //Also, do *something* here - at least log it somewhere
            //Empty catch blocks are evil to debug and reason about
        }
    }
```

The above is one idea - you may choose to do it slightly differently if you e.g. want to remove delegates that throw.

Comment: DynamicInvoke is convenient but also a little slow. Just to note that it could be replaced.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of those tricky things. Event handlers *must not return values*. This includes throwing exceptions, if you want things to be reasonably deterministic. What can the handler invoker really do about an exception being thrown?

But your example makes it very clear that your problem is in the handler itself - fix the handler. It's not supposed to throw exceptions just because a game object no longer exists!  You also need to make sure that all the handlers are properly removed from the event at an appropriate time. It sounds like your handlers are persisting in the event, when they should have long been removed.

Answer (score 0):

A better design would be to call a single method, and within that method call the two methods you need to call, as this would increase [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).

```
myEvent+=myEvent_handler

void myEvent_handler()
{
  try
  {
     MyMethod1();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     //handle it
  }
  try
  {
     MyMethod2();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //handle it
  }
```

}

EDIT: I just noticed the exceptions part of your question. You can then handle the exceptions easily like you would normally.